# Remix - Create new file not working

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm literally just trying to create a new file in remix and it is not working. Same goes for new folder. When I try to create a new file/folder the empty bar appears for me to type in and yet I cannot type anything. No cursor shows in the bar either. If I click away from the bar or even press enter it completely disappears as if I never attempted to create a new file at all.

[image: new file attempt]

Comment: It is working now. In that situation you may try another browser chrome, brave, firefox, running in a "private" window. Also you can report to their github project https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project.

Comment: It is NOT working....I literally cannot type anything in the box to write the name of the file. If i hit any key it immediately disappears. I know I can open another browser like chrome and work from there but I want to work with Safari and remix will not let me create new files or folders on Safari. To repeat, it is NOT working. Still. Even if I just open a new window. Reboot. Nothing.

Comment: You didn't mention Safari previously, I've tested with Chrome, Firefox, Brave and I was able to create a file. As mentioned previously try reporting in remix-ide github project, they have a similar issue open for ipads https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project/issues/1505.

Comment: The same is happening to me. Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It did not work for me either when I used Safari. It works on Google Chrome.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Aye, apparently there seems to be an issue with safari. Go on and try with another browser, works smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, worked after switching to the Brave browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try it on Incognito mode on chrome.
Ctrl + Shift + N

Answer (score 0):

I did it on firefox and worked smoothly for me

Answer (score 0):

You can click on this icon to create new file:

[image]