# Can’t type in new file under contracts!

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, remix

I can not type anything under new contracts! It flashes a keyboard on my phone but nothing is writing! Tried safari and google chrome

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could try loading Remix in Firefox or Brave. I'm pretty sure it work with Chrome for MacOS. Safari used to not work.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Remix - Create new file not working](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/110456/remix-create-new-file-not-working) but StackExchange is probably not the right place to report this. This seems to have already been reported in [#1505](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project/issues/1505). Please consider posting info about your browser/system/hardware there to help narrow it down.